# LAC and CID on LTE android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I used this method to read cell id and Lac(tac) on a LTE network but now it fails with `NullPointer exception`. Here is my code:

```
CellInfoLte cellinfolte = (CellInfoLte) mTelephonyMgr.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
String ssignal = cellinfolte.toString();
String[] parts = ssignal.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the followings in LTE networks:

`cellinfolte.getCellIdentity().getCi()`

`cellinfolte.getCellIdentity().getTac()`

Answer (score 0):

getAllCellInfo() is not implemented in most android phones (especially Samsung)

Answer (score 0):

You May Try This

```
     TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
      GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();  
      int cid = cellLocation.getCid();
      int lac = cellLocation.getLac();
```

Comment: This is for gsm not LTE !